# getting installed applications programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the installed application in Android after clicking a icon. Under the icon click code I wrote following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
startActivity(intent);
```

But it kills the application. I want to show the installed applications on the screen programmatically like when we see when press app key on Android.

Is it possible?
where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get list of all installed application you can use the following code

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Comment: It does not do anything if I click the icon. it shows mt the  pkgAppsList not used. If I use startActivity(mainIntent) it shows me the list of activity with app resolver which ask user to choose a activity to complete the action. Is there anyway to get only the list?